# What is the complexity of networkx.is_isomorphic?

Tags: time-complexity, networkx, complexity-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, isomorphism

What is the complexity of `networkx.is_isomorphic(graph1, graph2)`?
I am particularly interested to know it in the case of directed acyclic graphs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documents of [`nx.is_isomorphic`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#id2) the vf2-algorithm is implemented and even the original scientific reference is given.

> "L. P. Cordella, P. Foggia, C. Sansone, M. Vento, “An Improved Algorithm for Matching Large Graphs”, 3rd IAPR-TC15 Workshop on Graph-based Representations in Pattern Recognition, Cuen, pp. 149-159, 2001."

The boost library states for the [vf2-algorithm](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/graph/doc/vf2_sub_graph_iso.html#cordella2004) the following complexity:

> "The spatial complexity of VF2 is of order O(V), where V is the (maximum) number of vertices of the two graphs. Time complexity is O(V^2) in the best case and O(V!·V) in the worst case."